# Java Reflection Resources

Tags: java, reflection

Where can I find a document to understand about JAVA/Reflection like below code ?

> Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers")

**What is getDeclaredField does?**

**What is a term "modifiers" do ?**

I have seen reflection code in action from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/2077479)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is `getDeclaredField` does?

The method [`getDeclaredField(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-)

> Returns a `Field` object that reflects the specified declared field of
>   the class or interface represented by this `Class` object.

---

> What is a term "modifiers" do ?

"*modifiers*" here represents the name of the field to retrieve, as stated into the javadoc:

> The name parameter is a `String` that specifies the simple name of the desired field.

---

To summarize `Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers")`, will get by reflection the field [`modifiers`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/reflect/Field.java/#71) from the class `Field`.

```
 public final class Field extends AccessibleObject implements Member {
      ...
      private int                 modifiers; <-- this
      ...
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/reflect/Field.html) which should be the first place you look when something is puzzling you.